# How to call PHP file from a shell script file

Tags: php, bash, shellexecute

I need a shell script which has a loop. In each loop iteration it needs to call a PHP file with some parameters. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: the parameter is passed to the PHP in form of query string, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your php file named test.php, for example

```
<?php
//like programs in c language, use $argc, $argv access command line argument number and arguments, uncomment below two line to dump $argc and $argv
//var_dump($argc); //an integer
//var_dump($argv); //an array with arguments
//use args and do anything you want
echo "do my job\n";
exit(0);
```

then create a shell script named test.sh

```
#! `which bash`
php=`which php`
i=10
while [[ $i -ge 0 ]];
do  
$php test.php 1 2
((i--))
done
```

put the two files into the same directory. Then run command in the `terminal`

```
bash test.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If this means a Linux/Unix shell

```
for i in `seq 4`; do
    php myscript.php param1 param2
done
```

But since PHP has loops too, you can do this in PHP as well.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
    system("php myscript.php param1 param2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#Script to test for loop
#
#

    while [condition] 
    do
    php test.file
    done
```