# PHP include to start several other PHP scripts via CRON

Tags: php, android, cron

I am using Cron Tabs to send notifications to my android APP, 
but now I ran into a problem, my Host Provider has limited CronTab-s to 5, but I have 7 PHP files which I need to run in 3 separate times.

So my idea was, all that I need to run at the same time i "Group" and run them together, but I am not able to to that because PHP seems to include only the first one and then stops with that and does not include next one.

```
<?php 
include("push_n_lisatud.php");
include("push_n_muudetud.php");
?>
```

is there any workaround for that or I am on the very wrong route to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: You can do 3 Shell script launching the php scripts you want

Comment: Does the files end with something like "exit();"?
This will terminate the entire script

Comment: Sadly my host provider does net let me use shell.

I have MySqli close and Curl Close, may this be the issue?

Comment: Well seems that i lied. i can run Ruby, sh, and pyton also. 
Now.. something new to learn again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Includes are not a good way to ensure several independent PHP scripts are executed. This can create a lot of problems, e.g. if one PHP script has an hard exit somewhere (e.g. `die()`) the next script will not be called. Same when errors occur.

A better approach would be to call them in a shell script and call the shell script from `cron`.

Or if you have a lot of restrictions on your webserver and are limited to PHP scripts, you can use PHP to start several other PHP scripts asynchronously with `curl`.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611839/running-script-in-background-using-php-curl/48612058#48612058) for details on how to do that.

Comment: Ty for tip, do you have any exampels for that also? never done any shells :)

Comment: There are many examples if you do a little research. here is one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855666/how-to-call-php-file-from-a-shell-script-file).